# Al intentar cargar un archivo a una base de datos, me aparece la siguiente excepción: InvalidOperationException, en C#

Tags: c#

Al intentar cargar un archivo, para importarlo a una base de datos Mysql, me aparecen las excepciones:

> ReadTimeout = 'oFile.ReadTimeout' inició una excepción de tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'

> WriteTimeout = 'oFile.WriteTimeout' inició una excepción de tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'

El código, en C# es:

```
if (File.Exists(ficheroRegistros)) {
    //Carga el fichero
    FileStream oFile = File.Open(ficheroRegistros, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    ////Carga el fichero en la cultura seleccionada para el fichero
    this.TratarRegistrosDatos(cultura, idModeloBalanza, idConfiguracion, idIdiomaIngredientes, idIdiomaTextoArticulos, idConfiguracionReceta, idConfiguracionTrazabilidad, idConfiguracionFamilia, oFile, sRegistrosTratar, posicionRegistro, destinoEtiquetas);
    oFile.Close();
    oFile.Dispose();
}
```

Con otros archivos, no tengo ese problema. He visto documentación, pero no consigo dar con el problema. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: y donde esta tu codigo para escribir o leer? ahi simplemente se ve el metodo principal pero toda la info que le pasas o como lee el archivo no lo vemos.

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` puede ser generada por una amplia variedad de casos. Revisa el StackTrace en los detalles de la `Exception`, allí podrás encontrar indicios del punto donde se produce la falla y podrás publicar el bloque de código apropiado para mejorar tu pregunta.